# Best way to arrange multiple divs vertically one below the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

As the title says I am looking for the best solution to arrange many (dynamically generated) divs (all have same width!) one below the other. I have 2 suggestions so far:

1. float:left...
2. use an unordered list and surround every div with `li`

I personally prefer suggestion #2. What do you think?

Comment: What about `display: inline-block;` ?

Comment: You are aware that "horizontally" and "one below the other" mean completely opposite things right?

Comment: Sorry i mixed up horizontally and vertically :( Question has been edited.

Comment: If you just want them stacked vertically, the default `display: block` behavior of a div will do that automatically (`block` level elements include an implied line break afterward unless they are floated or other special situations).  Floating them left will make them line up horizontally instead, as will using `display: inline-block`.  Using a `ul` to wrap all of it is more of a semantic question than a functional one. You don't need to declare `display:block` as `div` elements already have this property by default.

Comment: By default divs stack on top of each other.  Have you actually tried anything yet?

Comment: @Felipe Miosso in both cases i would use jQuery in terms of appending the resulting div (from ajax call) to the previous element. So i think this could be handled more easily by using a list.

Comment: @user2948467 why cant you just output the divs as they are?

Comment: @Ennui and all others: Thanks! I will use the default behaviour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div { display: block; }
```

This should display all divs as block elements and take up the full width, thus the following divs should stack below.